# Why does SVD result of Armadillo differ from NumPy?

Tags: c++, python, numpy, linear-algebra, armadillo

In my Python code, I was computing SVD of some data using [numpy.linalg.svd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html):

```
from numpy import linalg
(_, _, v) = linalg.svd(m)
```

V matrix returned by this was:

```
[[ 0.4512937  -0.81992002 -0.35222884]
 [-0.22254721  0.27882908 -0.93419863]
 [ 0.86417981  0.4999855  -0.05663711]]
```

While porting my code to C++, I switched to using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) for computing SVD:

```
#include <armadillo>

arma::fmat M; // Input data
arma::fmat U;
arma::fvec S;
arma::fmat V;
arma::svd(U, S, V, M);
```

The resulting V for the same data is:

```
  0.4513  -0.2225  -0.8642
 -0.8199   0.2788  -0.5000
 -0.3522  -0.9342   0.0566
```

We can see that the transpose of V from Armadillo matches V from NumPy. Except that is, for the last column of V from Armadillo. Those values have the opposite sign of the values in last row of NumPy result.

What is happening here? Why do the SVD results from two popular libraries differ like this? And which of the two is the correct result?

Comment: What is the original matrix you apply your SVD to? Can you guarantee it's identical between the two systems? Usually the only difference might be the scale of the eigenvectors...

Comment: @AlexanderL.Belikoff: Yes, the input data is identical. In C++, the type is float and in Python it is double I guess. But, that amount of precision difference should not matter?

Comment: Technically the SVD decomposition is not unique (not sure about that change of sign tho). Beside that, probably one of the two is returning V* instead of V, hence the transpose. Moreover,in the SVD of a real square matrix produces an U and a V which are both rotation matrices, `armadillo` is correct in that. Can you post your original matrix?

Comment: @sbabbi: Input matrix is not square. It is shared here: http://pastebin.com/bPgKER7E

Comment: Armadillo returns `V` while numpy returns `V*`. As for the change of sign, I have no idea, but probably both results are correct, and that change of sign in `V` is balanced by another one in `U`. You can compute U*S*V and check that it is equal to your original matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct... The rows of the `v` you got from numpy are the eigenvectors of `M.dot(M.T)` (the transpose would be a conjugate transpose in the complex case). Eigenvectors are in the general case defined only up to a multiplicative constant, so you could multiply any row of `v` by a different number, and it will still be an eigenvector matrix.

There is the additional constraint on `v` that it be a [unitary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), which loosely translates to its rows being orthonormal. This reduces your available choices for every eigenvector to only 2: the normalized eigenvector pointing in either direction. But you still get to multiply any row by -1 and still have a valid `v`.

If you want to test it for your matrix, which I have loaded as `a`:

```
>>> u, d, v = np.linalg.svd(a)
>>> D = np.zeros_like(a)
>>> idx = np.arange(a.shape[1])
>>> D[idx, idx] = d
>>> np.allclose(a, u.dot(D).dot(v))
True
>>> v[2] *= -1
>>> np.allclose(a, u.dot(D).dot(v))
True
```

---

Actually, you can only multiply the rows of `v` by -1 in the real domain, but in the complex case you can multiply them by any complex number of absolute value 1:

```
>>> vv = v.astype(np.complex)
>>> vv[0] *= (1+1.j)/np.sqrt(2)
>>> np.allclose(a, u.dot(D).dot(v))
True
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime! I'm using v to rotate the points, like in PCA. So, I guess no harm in using the V I get from Armadillo for this?

Comment: Yes, the alignment of your axes will not change, the only difference is the [orientation of your basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)), which shouldn't be a relevant issue in most cases. Note that, at least in this case, it is numpy that is giving the usual right hand orientation of the basis. Again, I don't think the difference should be relevant for aligning your data.